# Change JFileChooser to a Microsoft look and feel?

Tags: java

Is there any better option than JFileChooser. I would like to have the windows look in my application and Java JFileChooser. Is there a way to customize the JFileChooser or to change the look. I know about look and feel but will that work for my purposes. The JFileChooser works but it has the old 80s look to it and that is not what I want and neither do the users of the program.

**Question: Can you turn the JFileChooser into a Microsoft Look and Feel?**

Code:

```
package TestMenu;

import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FileChooserDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static private final String newline = "\n";
    JButton openButton;
    JButton saveButton;
    JTextArea log;
    JFileChooser fc;

    public FileChooserDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        log = new JTextArea(5,20);
        log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        log.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

        fc = new JFileChooser();

        openButton = new JButton("Open a File...");
        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        saveButton = new JButton("Save a File...");
        saveButton.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        buttonPanel.add(openButton);
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);

        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            } else {
                log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        } else if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            } else {
                log.append("Save command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = FileChooserDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new FileChooserDemo());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createAndShowGUI();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of cause, if you are on a Microsoft Plattform then try in your JFrame class

```
try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: is the MainFrame.class.getName... is that the name of my class that I put this code in. It works and that is what I did so I was just wondering.

Comment: You should have a class which extends JFrame and where you call add(FileChooserDemo()) to the contentPane, and there you place the above code.

Comment: I do that. But MainFrame.class.getName().log... etc is that the name of my class because I tried it with MainFrame class and it told me to create a class called MainFrame. So i figured that was incorrect. Then by accident I changed it to the name of a class that is in the same package and it gave no errors. Then I realized that it probably was supposed to be the class that I am working in so I put it as that, and there were no errors.

Comment: Vice Versa can you make it look like a Mac on a Windows machine.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible, because of copyright "problems", if you want to have the same look and feel on every plattform just use ´CrossPlatformLookAndFeel´, this is the "Java Look and Feel", it is also called ´Metal´.

Comment: If your on a mac what is the string?

Comment: UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); With this you can set the Look and Feel of your current Plattform to your Java Appication.